# What does this documentation syntax mean in MDN for : inherit css tag

Tags: css

I have a basic question , refer to section as an example

> Constituent properties in  [list-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)

how do I interpret this statement of : inherit wherever it gets mentioned in mdn docs  in a layman/ generic form?
I also see Inherited value as Yes in *Formal definition* section so is it connected to *:inherit* in any way or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

> The inherit CSS keyword causes the element to take the computed value
> of the property from its parent element. It can be applied to any CSS
> property, including the CSS shorthand property all.

Comment: how I can see the parent elements and the child elements visually in chrome browser?

Comment: Open the page in Chrome, then press Ctrl-Shift-I to open the Developer tools and select the Elements tab. [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/). If you have specific questions about Dev Tools, ask a new question.